# proxy setting in network option doesn't work. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, proxy

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I add Socks of Tor for proxy by network option but it doesn't work
It always worked on Ubuntu 16.04 but now it doesn't work
thank you.

Comment: Where doesn't it work? How have you verified that it is not working?

Comment: @vidarlo I try to access some blocked websites in my country, but I can't. And I use Firefox, if it matters

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Firefox, I installed google chrome and it works very well with proxy added in network options, but still I don't know what was the problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has probably its own Network settings - you can check that in Firefox - preferences - Network settings and change the settings if necessary.